# iPhone: Two UItableviews; segmented control to toggle

Tags: iphone

I have a xib with a view which contains two views which each contain a tableview shortened in height. The root view has a segmented controller which should toggle the views. How can I make each tableview point to it's appropriate class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to add two UITableViewController classes to your project from File->Add, then click on Include Xib option. This will create the two table views xib files along with. You can then init the two controllers while in your main controller's ViewDidLoad event, and assign them a frame that is equal to the left & right views you have as follows:

```
[firstTableController.view setFrame:rightView.frame];
[secondTableController.view setFrame:leftView.frame];
```

Where both rightView & leftView are UIView * objects that are hooked to your two views in IB.

You can then simply add the two table controllers to your main view controller using addSubView from the main controller:

```
[self.view addSubView:firstTableController.view];
[self.view addSubView:secondTableController.view];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's genius. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

{

```
int x;
if (tableView.tag == 100)
{
    x = [tab1 count];
}


  if (tableView.tag == 101)


 {
    x = [tab2 count];
}
return x;

}
```

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier =  @"Helllo";


UITableViewCell    *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}





if (tableView.tag ==100)
{
    cell.textLabel.text= [tab1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
}
 if (tableView.tag == 101)
{
     cell.textLabel.text=[tab2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
}


cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


return cell;
```

}

tab1 and tab2 are arrays.